# ClassNotFoundException while attempting to connect SQL Server through rest API?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, sqljdbc

I have a rest API service deployed which has a method where it attempts to connect to SQL Server. Locally before deployment, this all worked fine but now I get the error that the `Sqljdbc` file is missing.
Below is the exception

> java web service java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Found many posts online here where suggestions to ensure library is in correct folder:
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/sqljdbc4.jar

WEB-INF/sqljdbc4.jar

I also added it to the folder /WEB-INF/lib/sqljdbc4.jar

Still I get the error. Any ideas or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Does this sqljdbc4.jar contains mentioned class? Qualified name (package + class name) match is important.

Comment: are you using compatible versions. the you are using is available in respected jar file.

Comment: Have you checked that the driver is actually included in the deployment?

Comment: the driver is included in the deployment;

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the system requirements of your server middleware are matching? Compare to this MS documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Do not forget to restart the server after adding the JAR.

Comment: So this is related to tomcat recognizing the driver and not the actual project?

Comment: My guess is that it is either the wrong JRE version or the latter. Could there be a second sqljdbc*.jar in this tomcat installation?